# .exe файл не открывается. input стоит в конце

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

с помощью pyinstaller сделал в консоле pyinstaller main.py и после открытия .exe файла он сразу закрывается. Причина - не известна. Как вы видите в конце стоит input() и всё равно ничего не помогает. Заранее спасибо. Код:

```
import sys,time

print("Хотите начать игру? ")
A = input()
print()

QUEST = {
"intro"         : ("""
Я видел какой-то сон, кто-то тянулся к синему кристалу
Потом стало темно
Мне кажется я здесь не один...

S.T.A.L.K.E.R
""", "goto", "meet_vadim"
),
"meet_vadim"    : ("""
\tВадим: Мда, интересно как тебя сюда занесло
""", "question", {"Где я?"                  : "vadik1"}
),
"vadik1"        : ("""
\tВадим: Ты в Зоне. Как тебя звать?
""", "question", {"В какой зоне?"           : "vadik2",
                  "А как тебя?"             : "vadik3",
                  "Я не помню своего имени.": "vadik4"}
),
"vadik2"        : ("""
\tВадим: Всмысле в какой? В Зоне Очуждения.
""", "question", {"В ЗОНЕ ОЧУЖДЕНИЯ?!"      : "vadik5"}
),
"vadik3"        : ("""
\tВадим: Вадим.
""", "question", {"Приятно позакомится."    : "vadik6"}
),
"vadik4"        : ("""
\tВадим: Мда, плохи дела. Ну нечего, следуй за мной. 
\t       Я покажу тебе дорогу в уромное местечко. Отсюда недалеко.
""", "question", {"Ну пойдём."              : "vadik7"}
),
"vadik5"        : ("""
\tВадим: Ну да.
""", "question", {"Во попал!"               : "vadik8"}
),
"vadik6"        : ("""
\tВадим: Так как тебя зовут?
""", "question", {"Не помню!"               : "vadik9",
                  "Я помню только 3 первых буквы 'Бро...'" : "vadik11"}
),
"vadik7"        : ("""
\tВадим: Следуй за мной.
""", "action",   {"Следовать за Вадиком"    : "go_vadik",
                  "Поговорить"              : "speak_vadik"}
),
"vadik8"        : ("""
\tВадим: Пошли за мной. Покажу укромное местечко.
""", "question", {"Ну пойдём"               : "vadik_go_act"}
),
"vadik9"        : ("""
\tВадим: Какой-то ты раздражительный.
""", "question", {"А ты как думал? Голова пухнет, нечего не помню." : "vadik12",
                  "...."                    : "vadik13"}
),
"vadik_go_act"   : ("""
""", "action",   {"Следовать за Вадиком"    : "go_vadik",
                  "Поговорить"              : "speak_vadik"}
),
"vadik11"        : ("""
\tВадим: Сочувствую. Ну ладно. Пойдём за мной, я знаю место где можно отдохнуть. 
\t       Может и имя своё вспомнишь.
""", "question", {"Ну пойдём"               : "vadik_go_act"}
),
"vadik12"        : ("""
\tВадим: Ну ладно. Пойдём за мной, я знаю место где можно отдохнуть.
""", "question", {"Пойдём"                  : "vadik_go_act"}
),
"vadik13"        : ("""
\tВадим: Пойдём за мной, я знаю место где можно отдохнуть.
""", "question", {"Пошли"                   : "vadik_go_act"}
),
"go_vadik"        : ("""
Все ушли в закат.
""", "goto", "outro"
),
"speak_vadik"     : ("""
Вы попытались заговорить с Вадимом, но тут яркая вспышка озарила небо.
""", "goto", "outro"
),
"outro"           : ("""
КОНЕЦ.
""", "exit", ""
)
}

def slow_print(str):
    for letter in str + '\n':
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(3./90)
    print()

def go(quest, stage="intro"):
    while True:
        text, type, action = quest[stage]
        slow_print(text.lstrip("\n"))
        if type == "goto":
            stage = action
            time.sleep(1)
        elif type in ("question", "action"):
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"/// Выберете {'ответ' if type == 'question' else 'действие'} ({'/'.join(map(str, range(1, len(action)+1)))}) ///")
                variants = list(action.items())
                for i, question in enumerate(variants, 1):
                    print(f"/// {i}. {question[0]}")
                answer = input()
                if answer.isdigit():
                    answer = int(answer)
                    if 0 < answer <= len(action):
                        if type == "question":
                            slow_print(f"\tВы: {variants[answer-1][0]}")
                        stage = variants[answer-1][1]
                        break
                print("Ваш ответ не ясен. Повторите.")
        elif type == "exit":
            return

go(QUEST)

input()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какой командой вы собираете exe

Comment: pyinstaller -F main.py

Comment: @Phantom907 данный вариант у меня также работает, попробуйте заново создать ваше виртуальное окружение и попробовать снова

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить pyinstaller предыдущей версии:

```
pip install pyinstaller==4.5
```

Создайте .exe стандартным способом

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

Откройте полученный результат в папке dist:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: может надо как то удалить прошлый pyinstaller

Comment: @Phantom907 вы создаете venv при работе? если да, то удалите venv и создайте новый через python -m venv venv и снова установите pyinstaller

Comment: удалить папку venv и сделать заново по команде

Comment: Но как удалить pyinstaller?

Comment: @Phantom907 pip uninstall pyinstaller

Comment: не работает ())))

Comment: @Phantom907 а ты venv активируешь через консоль? source venv/bin/activate

Comment: всм?  )) это как

Comment: @Phantom907 добавь, пожалуйста, в вопрос скриншот твоей IDE (или консольки) где ты создаешь .exe